# Selenium WebDriver, trying to set value attribute of input element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an input element, which is the following:

```
<input id="contestant[name]" name="name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }" ng-model="contestantState.form.name" ng-pattern=".*" placeholder="Alice Smith" required="" style="width: 246px" type="text" class="ng-valid-pattern ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
```

I'm trying to use Selenium to send text to this element, I've tried the following:

```
fullname = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='contestant[name]']")
fullname.send_keys("Test Name")
```

However, this gives me the infamous

```
Element <...> is not reachable by keyboard
```

So I tried to use `execute_script` to change the `value` attribute, as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'Full Name');", fullname)
```

Which also doesn't work. However, when I use the Firefox developer console, and locate the element and set the attribute as below, it does work.

```
$0.setAttribute('value', 'Test Name')
```

The only issue with the above is that I still need to click on the element after I've changed the `value` attribute for it to be accepted, but that's the next step to figure out.

Any ideas why my `execute_script` differs from the console?

EDIT: I just noticed that when I use `execute_script` to set the `value` attribute, it is visible in the `innerHTML` attribute, just not on the webpage.

```
print(driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('contestant[name]').parentNode.innerHTML"))

<input id="contestant[name]" name="name" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }" ng-model="contestantState.form.name" ng-pattern=".*" placeholder="Alice Smith" required="" style="width: 246px" type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" value="Full Name">
<div class="help-inline" ng-hide="contestantEditForm.name.$viewValue">Required</div>
```

Comment: Try to click first and then send keys. Also you may need to wait for element to be clickable

Comment: I tried this, but I get a time-out waiting for it to be clickable. When you load the page as per usual, this element already has focus.

Comment: Did I tell you that, the question heading _trying to set value attribute_, your actual problem _send text to this element_ and your final question _I still need to click on the element after I've changed the value_, are completely 3 different things and cannot be answered in a single question?